# SAS cleaning messy datasets

Tags: sas

I have this messy dataset which I wanted to import into SAS

```
Datelisted, Shop, Region, Product, Color, Price, Discount, Contacts 
"[{"date":"12/03/20","listed by":"Josh"}]", MelB, "New York, Houston, Boston, Seattle", "Pental Fountain, 5""5, metallic", "Red, Blue, Black, Green", 12.30, No, "[{"name":"Josh","contact":"+12717111"}, {"name":"Marine","contact":"+13681811"}]"
"[{"date":"22/05/21","listed by":"Marrie"}]", Shop Japan, "Tokyo, Los Angeles, Melbourne", "Faser Kean, gold, 4""", "Black", 14.50, Yes, "[{"name":"Moseaih","contact":"+1235199191"}, {"name":"James","contact":"+11717711"}, {"name":"Francis","contact":"+1172271"}]"
"[{"date":"01/01/21","listed by":"user"}]", , "New York, Boston, Washington D. C.", Kirnawa, PS, pattern, 5""", ,23.12, , "[{"name":"Moseaih","contact":"+1235199191"}]"
"[{"date":"17/03/25","listed by":"user"}]", Trailer Price, "Sydney, New York, Chicago", "Ink Bladez, 4""", "Blue, Green, Yellow, Black, Pink", 34.23, , ,
```

Im trying to use SAS program instead of manually edit the datasets to clean the data,know how is it possible?

Comment: Looks like a CSV (comma separated values) file.  What  is it that you want to "clean"?  Do you want to parse the fields that appear to have JSON style text in them? Show what you tried and explain why it was not what you wanted.

Comment: What is the source of that psuedo CSV file text?  Can you request that the CSV file be re-created from the original, only this time as a properly formatted CSV file?

Comment: Is this the original file or was it originally JSON or XML?

Comment: You totally can clean that with SAS, but all I can say is that really is an evil JSON-CSV hybrid that someone put together.

Answer (score 1):

The program below will read this CSV-like JSON-esque file. The idea is to read each line as one large line, then parse it using combinations of `scan`, loops, and identifying patterns in the data. Note that you are missing a quotation mark on the third line before "Kirnawa." This had to be added to read the line successfully.

```
data want;
    infile datalines firstobs=2 length=len;
    input line$varying32767. len;

    length date 8.
           listed_by $15.
           shop      
           region
           product
           color     $50.
           price     8.
           discount  $10.;
    ;

    format date  ddmmyys8.
           price dollar32.2
    ;
        

    array contact[5]        $100.;              /* Change max number of contacts here */
    array contact_line[100] $100. _TEMPORARY_;  /* Holds temporary strings of interest for contacts */

    date      = input(substr(line, 12, 8), ddmmyy10.);  /* Date is always 8 chars long and starting on the 12th column */
    listed_by = dequote(scan(line, 3, ':}' ));          /* The listed-by individual is always the third word in the string after ':' and '}' */

    /* Treat the rest like a CSV file. Ignore commas within quotes. */
    shop      = dequote(scan(line, 2, ',', 'QR') );         
    region    = dequote(scan(line, 3, ',', 'QR') );
    product   = dequote(scan(line, 4, ',', 'QR') );
    color     = dequote(scan(line, 5, ',', 'QR') );
    price     = input(scan(line, 6, ',', 'QR'), 8.);
    discount  = dequote(scan(line, 7, ',', 'QR') );

    /* All contacts in the JSON-like format */
    contacts   = scan(line, 8, ',', 'Q');

    /* Count the number of contacts and loop through each one */
    n_contacts = count(scan(line, 8, ',', 'Q'), '"name":');

    /* Contacts always follow this format:
        "[{"name":"NAME1","contact":"+12345678"}, {"name":"NAME2","contact":"+1234567"}, {"NAMR3":"Francis","contact":"+1234567"}]"
        
        Grab each individual contact and extract the name and phone number.
        {"name":"NAME1","contact":"+12345678"} --> name = 2nd after the ':', phone = 4th word after the ':' and ','
        {"name":"NAME2","contact":"+1234567"}  --> name = 2nd after the ':', phone = 4th word after the ':' and ','
    */
    do i = 1 to n_contacts*2;
        contact_line[i] = scan(contacts, i, '{}');

        /* When we scan through the contact line in this way, every other column contains the full contact name */
        if(mod(i, 2) = 0) then do;
            contact[i/2] = catx(', ', dequote(scan(contact_line[i], 2, ':,', 'R') ), dequote(scan(contact_line[i], 4, ':,', 'R') ) );
        end;
    end;
    
    drop contacts n_contacts i line;

    datalines;
Datelisted, Shop, Region, Product, Color, Price, Discount, Contacts 
"[{"date":"12/03/20","listed by":"Josh"}]", MelB, "New York, Houston, Boston, Seattle", "Pental Fountain, 5""5, metallic", "Red, Blue, Black, Green", 12.30, No, "[{"name":"Josh","contact":"+12717111"}, {"name":"Marine","contact":"+13681811"}]"
"[{"date":"22/05/21","listed by":"Marrie"}]", Shop Japan, "Tokyo, Los Angeles, Melbourne", "Faser Kean, gold, 4""", "Black", 14.50, Yes, "[{"name":"Moseaih","contact":"+1235199191"}, {"name":"James","contact":"+11717711"}, {"name":"Francis","contact":"+1172271"}]"
"[{"date":"01/01/21","listed by":"user"}]", , "New York, Boston, Washington D. C.", "Kirnawa, PS, pattern, 5""", ,23.12, , "[{"name":"Moseaih","contact":"+1235199191"}]"
"[{"date":"17/03/25","listed by":"user"}]", Trailer Price, "Sydney, New York, Chicago", "Ink Bladez, 4""", "Blue, Green, Yellow, Black, Pink", 34.23, , , 
;
run;
```

Output:
[image]

SAS certainly can handle this file without a problem, and there are many other ways to read this file within SAS. For a one-off file this will be okay, but if I received a file like this to be incorporated in a regular production process, I'd ask them to send it another more structured format. It simply has too many ways it can go wrong, and you don't want to be supporting a file that requires such complex steps to read unless absolutely necessary.

Comment: If you can fix that one missing quote from that one line then just change the double quotes around the JSON text to single quotes will allow the lines to be read as comma delimited. Just change "[ and ]" to '[ and ]'.  Then parsing the JSON text can be a separate activitiy.

Comment: what does "input line$varying32767. len;" mean?

Comment: `input` says to read a column in the data. We are calling this column `line`. `$varying` is an informat that says each record may have a varying width as it is read. `32767.` says the max length of the line could be 32,767 bytes. `len` is a variable that gives SAS the length of the record, which we specified in the `infile` statement. `$varying` requires that `len` is also used with it in the input statement (e.g. `input var $varying. len`). This is a unique informat that requires this specific syntax. It's great for reading everything into a single column, like HTML.